# Make dynamically created panels in winform responsive (same size as my flowlayoutPanel) - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, responsive, dynamically-generated, flowlayoutpanel

So I'm creating some panels with the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int xlocation = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            {
                panel.Name = string.Format("{0}", i);
                panel.Text = string.Format(i.ToString());
                panel.BackColor = Color.White;
                panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xlocation, 30);
                panel.Width = flowLayoutPanel1.Width;
                panel.Height = 50;
                panel.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.panel_MouseEnter);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);



                Label label = new Label();
                label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 10);
                label.AutoSize = true;
                label.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 13F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
                label.Text = string.Format("{0}", "GNU" + i);
                panel.Controls.Add(label);

                Label label10 = new Label();
                label10.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 35);
                label10.AutoSize = true;
                label10.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                label10.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
                label10.Text = string.Format("{0}", "hest");
                panel.Controls.Add(label10);
            }
            xlocation = xlocation + 85;
        }
   }
```

The problem is when I resize my form, my flowLayoutPanel obviously gets bigger, but the panels inside doesn't.

I have tried using the

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any answer is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: [Control.Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JohnWu doesn't work, it only works on the latest created panel if I remove the for loop. I want all the panels to resize to the same width as the flowlayoutpanel, when I make my form bigger, or smaller.

Comment: A flowLayoutPanel  has limited properties. I find if I make my own array of panels using a regular panel I have more properties which usually solve these issues.  Every time I've tried using the flowLayoutPanel  I find that I can't do what I want and eventually change to a regular panel.

Comment: Read again my comment on your [previous, identical, question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65139768/7444103): 1) Make a UserControl, 2) Don't use a FlowLayoutPanel for this. Use a standard Panel or a TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Anchor property and set it to Right and Left, or can dock each panel to parent control. Something like this should work:

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top; // Docks the panel to top, and fills to the width of Parent control
panel.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left); // Set anchor to right and left
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just created a list with my panels like so

```
List<Panel> pnls = new List<Panel>();
```

And just did like so to make them follow the width of my flowlayoutpanel, so you can actually use a flowlayoutpanel ;-)

```
 private void Kontrol_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pnls.Count; i++)
        {
            pnls[i].Width = activityData.Width - 24;
            pnls[i].Height = activityData.Height / 4;
        }
    }
```